# Sql result to own Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to create Hash through sql result. Key of Hash it is result query and value it is result.

**Example:**

```
UsersPost.select('DISTINCT vk_group_id, MAX(date_send) as md')
  .where('vk_group_id = :vk_group_id ',{:vk_group_id=>39338677}).map do |result|
{result.vk_group_id: result.md}    
end

#=>{'223' => 'dsf'}
```

But it give me error:

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

Comment: If you are getting result `#=>{'223' => 'dsf'}` it simply means that there is no problem with the above code, and you are getting error somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to fill a hash

```
h = UsersPost.select('DISTINCT vk_group_id, MAX(date_send) as md')
      .where('vk_group_id = :vk_group_id ',{:vk_group_id=>39338677})
      .each_with_object({}) { |result, hash| hash[result.vk_group_id] = result.md }
```

Answer (score 2):

It may possible that your ruby version is prior to 1.9.3. and it is not accepting new hash form like `{key: 'value'}` and expecting `{:key => 'value'}`

Try following

```
UsersPost.select('DISTINCT vk_group_id, MAX(date_send) as md')
  .where('vk_group_id = :vk_group_id ',{:vk_group_id=>39338677}).map do |result|
{result.vk_group_id => result.md}    
end
```

Comment: Just writing the same answer but you posted it first :)

Comment: This solution returns an array of hashes, but I think the OP was looking for a single hash with all results.

Comment: @Baldrick:- May be, but i just answered his problem `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use the hash rocket syntax:

```
UsersPost.select('DISTINCT vk_group_id, MAX(date_send) as md')
  .where('vk_group_id = :vk_group_id ',{:vk_group_id=>39338677}).map do |result|
  {result.vk_group_id => result.md}    
end
```

but this would give you an array of hashes.  Try using inject instead.

```
UsersPost.select('DISTINCT vk_group_id, MAX(date_send) as md')
  .where('vk_group_id = :vk_group_id ',{:vk_group_id=>39338677}).inject({}) do |hash, user_post|
  hash[user_post.vk_group_id] = user_post.md   
end
```

each_with_object works also but that is a RoR method not ruby.  I prefer using ruby if it is available.